# Any way to fix luxury vinyl floating planks that keep coming apart?

Tags: flooring, adhesive, vinyl-flooring

I installed floating click-lock LVP (coretec pro plus) a year ago and In just one place, the edge between two planks slowly got wider. We tapped it back together from the end of the row, but after another few weeks it’s coming apart again. The subfloor underneath in this area is quite flat as far as I can tell.

In understand this is fairly common and that manufacturers just tell you to tap them back in, but I’m converting this to a rental so that’s not particularly feasible. I saw in one thread here that someone suggested superglue for joining them together and I’m thinking of doing that. Any opinions / ideas / experience?

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I would tap all the pieces together so the joints are tight.  Then I would go to the end of the run (the end where all the extra space is now) and pull up the transition strip or shoe molding that hides that end.  Depending on how much space there is between that last plank and the wall, put in a small spacer followed by a dab or two of an elastomer sealer, like Silicone-II.  This should keep the planks tight, but allow them to move a bit with temperature changes after the sealer cures.

Comment: This is clever - I had not that about going at it from the edge, thanks @SteveSh!  The end of this one is in a doorway with a T-molding, but I think I should be able to rig up a spacer in there. Could you elaborate on exactly where to apply the sealer - to the end of the plank or to the spacer?  Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

mine has silicone around perimeter and they were still coming apart. I used wood glue and they haven't came apart since.....